# Securely storing toolboxes in a truck bed

Tags: ford, f-150, storage

I have my tools organized into boxes based on what I'm going to do, mostly on Dewalt's TSTAK line. I recently purchased a Ford F150 and am looking for the best way to carry / fasten these tool boxes in the truck bed, without having to empty them into permanent toolboxes in the truck (I still want to keep them organized, and easily carry them out) or spending a ton of time fastening each box / tower. Currently I just slide them on the truck bed, but they can slide around especially if I brake hard. Ratchet straps would be annoying to do for every box / tower every time I need to bring it.

For reference, I have something like this:

- [Deep toolbox](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N2IMKYO) for general tools, which I take and use everywhere.
- A tower of 1x [flat toolbox](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B6K4V80) + 2x sets of [drawers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BPI1TWO) for general electrical tools and parts.
- Various dedicated toolboxes for specialty things, e.g. a conduit parts box, a drywall repair box, a plumbing box, etc...

I'd prefer to stick to TSTAK since I already have them, but if there's another brand with a great way to fasten to a truck bed then I'd be willing to consider buying new boxes.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your truck bed should have built in dividers in the side of the bed. I don't know what year your vehicle is, but the ones I've seen have multiple ridges in the back. Here's an image of an F150 where I'm pointing it out:

[image]

These ridges are there so you can fit a board into them across the entire width. There are multiple so you can set the distance from the tailgate. In doing this, you create an area where the boxes can sit and not slide around. They are very easy access. The only thing you have to worry about is security of your boxes.

Comment: Thank you! This is probably the easiest way. I take it that floor mounts aren't a common thing then?

Comment: You can do whatever you want. If that means putting mounts into your bed, then go for it. Easily done. Not so easily undone. Using what is in the bed in the first place is a way to keep things where you want them, while still being able to dismantle it all and make it just like you bought it.